# Get total number of products currently in cart passing the user ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I am trying to figure out how to get total number of products currently in the cart. I would like to know if there is a woocommerce function that can fetch me the count of products in the cart by passing the user ID. I cannot find anything on the office documentation.

Please help me with this.

I tried this function but it only returns the total orders:

```
$i =  wc_get_customer_order_count($user_id);
```

And following a link I tried this too:

```
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
//print_r($items);
json_encode($items);
```

*I am new to WordPress and I would also like to know how to initialize $woocommerce.*

Answer (score 3):

The answer is (without any need of **`$user_id`** or **`global $woocommerce`**):

```
$items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
```

You will get the current customer cart items count.

> **There is NO user_id related to cart, as a non logged/registered user can add items in cart. So  this will not work for cart.**

Live cart is saved in **session** and current user has **a corresponding cookie** in his browser…

Answer (score 0):

To get this via Ajax so it updates when the total updates use this 
https://github.com/samisonline/ajax_cart

This has a cart counter, and separately a mini cart with details of each product